# How do i remove this error while executing publisher subscriber in ros?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i've got this error:

```
The specified base path "/home/dinesh/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials" contains a package but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace.
```

How can i remove it? I'm trying to run the pub/sub program.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234352/how-do-i-remove-this-error-while-executing-publisher-subscriber-in-ros?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-14

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error says `catkin_make` must be invoked in the root of the workspace. What this means is that you must change your directory to be in the root of the workspace before running `catkin_make`.

```
cd /home/dinesh/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

The tutorials make reference to this behavior. Although I think they often leave out an explicit call to `cd`. Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-05-15**:
got it, thanks, new to linux so, little confusion.